# Linux subsystem on windows cannot compile java code

Tags: windows, bash, javac

I have installed java, followed all the ubuntu specific advises that I found on SO.However, as I do `javac Program.java`, it looks like I'm entering an infinite loop.Just keep typing and can't even get out(even clt-c does not work).

**Reverse.java**

```
/**
 * This program echos the command-line arguments backwards.
 **/
public class Reverse {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Loop backwards through the array of arguments
    for(int i = args.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      // Loop backwards through the characters in each argument
      for(int j=args[i].length()-1; j>=0; j--) {
        // Print out character j of argument i.
        System.out.print(args[i].charAt(j));
      }
      System.out.print(" ");  // add a space at the end of each argument
    }
    System.out.println();     // and terminate the line when we're done.
  }
}
```

I can run other programs(Ruby, C++, C etc).There's sth that I'm missing here and I will appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: What is break on windows?

Comment: Just for information, windows has a new feature called "Linux subsystem".

Comment: Could you try other codes like  javac HelloWorld.java

Comment: No, but I can run other programs(Ruby, C++, C etc).There's sth that I'm missing here and I will appreciate any help.

Comment: This is a very new technology.  There might well be some bugs.